# Unity Coroutines C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как сделать универсальную корутину для запуска какой то функции через определённое время?

Ну, чтобы это выглядело как то так

```
StartCoroutine(WaitAndRun(3f,RunningMethod));


IEnumerator WaitAndRun(float time, out void RunningMethod(int i, int j)
{
yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
RunningMethod(i,j);
}

void RunningMethod(int i, int j)
{

}
```

Ну т.е. мы и так можем просто запустить с задержкой через корутину что то, но как это сделать универсальным? Аналог юнитевского

```
Invoke("RunningMethod", 3f)
```

Но с возможностью указывать метод прямо,а не через string и возможностью передавать аргументы.

Comment: Если совсем универсальную, смотри в сторону delegate+замыкания(лямбда функция), либо delegate+ params object[];
Но в погоде за универсальностью потеряешь производительность, и чем больше универсальности, тем более медленное(выделение чрезмерного кол-ва памяти, boxing-unboxing и т.д.).

Comment: @Xumera_hZ
Что значит "совсем универсальную"? Просто чтобы вызывать функции с аргументами с нужной задержкой, больше ничего от этого и не требуется.

Comment: ну можно сделать универсальные только для функции с 1,2,..N аргументами(жестко определенным кол-вом параметров). А можно с любым кол-вом параметров(params object[]) - это совсем универсальное решение.
Описать 4ре перегруженных запуска корутины с 1,2,3,4 параметрами может покрыть 90% вызовов и это будет гораздо быстрее работать. А для 5 и более можно прописать с (params object[]).

Comment: @Xumera_hZ
Боже, нет, зачем так сложно? Мне просто нужна адекватная замена "Invoke" в коде, достаточно решения того что я описал, с двумя аргументами.

Answer (score 2):

Могу посоветовать вам изучить что такое [Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) (расширения). Они позволяют расширять функционал любого класса, не вмешиваясь в его скрипт. Если использовать расширение для MonoBehaviour, универсальный метод будет выглядеть вот так:

```
    public static Coroutine WaitSecond(this MonoBehaviour obj, float seconds, Action action)
    {
        return obj.StartCoroutine(Timer(seconds, action));
    }

    static IEnumerator Timer(float timer, Action action)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
        action?.Invoke();
    }
```

А его вызов так:

```
void Method()
{
    this.WaitSecond(1f, ()=> Method2(1,"lol"));
}

void Method2(int first, string second)
{
    //делаем что нужно!
}
```

Здесь я использовал собственно сам статический метод расширения и [лямбда выражение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) (это та самая конструкция со стрелочкой и скобками).

Благодаря лямбе вы можете вызывать абсолютно любой метод и передавать в него нудные аргументы, а благодаря расширению - вызывать метод стартующий корутину из совершенно любого класса, который наследуется от MonoBehaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз надо для 2 переменных, вот 2 варианта

Основа

```
void RunningMethod(int i, int j)
{
}
```

1 способ вызова:

```
System.Action<int, int> runningMethod;

private void Awake()
{
    runningMethod = RunningMethod;
}

void Example()
{
    DeferredRun(runningMethod, 5, 6, 2f);
}
```

2.способ вызова:

```
void Example()
{
    DeferredRun(RunningMethod, 5, 6, 2f);
}
```

Разница в том, что во втором случае при каждом вызове будет создавать новый делегат из метода **RunningMethod**, а в первом закешировали сразу.

I вариант:

```
void DeferredRun<T,U>(System.Action<T, U> func, T a,U b, float timer = 0f)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndRun(timer, ()=> { func(a, b); }));
    }
    IEnumerator WaitAndRun(float time, System.Action func)
    {
        if(time<=0f)
        {
            if (func != null) func();
            yield break;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        if(func!=null) func();
    }
```

II вариант:

```
void DeferredRun<T, U>(System.Action<T, U> func, T a, U b, float timer = 0f)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitAndRun(timer, a, b, func));
    }
    IEnumerator WaitAndRun<T,U>(float time, T a, U b, System.Action<T, U> func)
    {
        if (time <= 0f)
        {
            if (func != null) func(a, b);
            yield break;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        if (func != null) func(a, b);
    }
```

В первом варианте создает лямбда-функция с замыканием(выделение памяти при каждом вызове), зато корутина более гибкой становится, в первом варианте более быстрый и ограничен 2мя параметрами.

**p.s.** Не стоит еще забывать, что корутина **не работает на выключенных объектах** и если запустить корутину на включенном, а потом выключить объект, то корутина остановится на всегда( у invoke нет такой проблемы). Поэтому тут либо надо контролировать включенность объекта(что крайне сложно иногда), либо сделать менеджер, который будет запускать функции других объектов независимо(и если все таки не надо запускать корутину, когда объект выключен, в этом менеджере  можно отдельно проверять активность объекта, также можно ждать когда объект снова включится. Придумать условий можно много).